# codebird issue with posting a tweet

Tags: javascript, twitter, titanium

I am calling this set tweet function ONLY when access tokens are not null. That part of the code is working fine and I receive an authorisation screen when the tokens are null. However, in this setTweet function, I am not getting any of the alerts apart from the first one can anyone tell me what might be going wrong?

```
var Codebird3 = require("codebird");

var cb3 = new Codebird3();

cb3.setConsumerKey('correctTokenHere', 'AndHere');

function setTweet(){
alert('In setTweet function');
       var tweet = 'I have just scored '+ globalPts +' points playing Clash of the Classics. Test your knowledge of the classic hits and see if you can beat my score. https://www.facebook.com/ClassicHits4FM/app_199377276878657';
        cb3.__call(
            "statuses_update",
                {"status": tweet },
                    function (reply) {
                    alert('In here');
                    function inspeccionar(obj){
                        alert('in reply part');
                        var msg = '';
                        for (var property in obj){
                            if (typeof obj[property] == 'function')
                            {
                                var inicio = obj[property].toString().indexOf('function');
                                var fin = obj[property].toString().indexOf(')')+1;
                                var propertyValue=obj[property].toString().substring(inicio,fin);
                                msg +=(typeof obj[property])+' '+property+' : '+propertyValue+' ;\n';
                            }
                            else if (typeof obj[property] == 'unknown')
                            {
                                msg += 'unknown '+property+' : unknown ;\n';
                            }
                            else
                                {
                                    msg +=(typeof obj[property])+' '+property+' : '+obj[property]+' ;\n';
                                }
                        }
                        return msg;
                        }

                        alert(inspeccionar(reply)); 
                        alert(reply.httpstatus);

                        if(reply.httpstatus == 200){
                                alert("Tweet sent!");
                                twitterBtn.setBackgroundImage('twitterShare_blue.png');

                         }
                         else{
                                alert(reply.errors);
                                //alert('Connection lost');
                         }
                }
        );
    //});
}
```

P.S. the strange thing is, I have pretty much the exact same function in another js in this app and it works. I'm working with Titanium which is basically just javascript for these purposes

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the tweet is restricted to 160 chars which I didn't realise!

Comment: To 140 characters, rather, like _any_ tweet.